# Showing content to selected user from his Profile type in elgg

Tags: ajax, widget, entity, friend, elgg

I have problem in friend of friends, when i add same one in my friend , his friend who are in my same profile type that list only show when i was open that friend page widgets.

example  i am a programmer profile type my friend have programmer,tester,designer , when i will open his profile in the widgets show only programmer friends.....

i try same code but i can't fulfill the code

```
$option = array( 'type'=>'user','subtype'=>'friends' 'where'=>'guid=')
```

please help me...... thanx adv........

Comment: I suggest you to post the same question on the ELGG's community forum. Probably you will find your answer faster there. Once, I've asked an ELGG related question here, and people told me to go on their forum if i wanted to get some solution.

Comment: There's not enough info to help here. Is "friend of friends" a 3rd party plugin?